# Activity get's recreated although I call finish

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, android-lifecycle

**Background**

I use a helper activity to determine when a floating widget (placed in the `WindowManager`) opens an activity, as I need to hide the floating widget then...

Therefore I create a transparent activity, that checks in `onPause` if the screen turned off or not. If not, I assume that an activity was opened by my floating widget.

**Problem**

Opening the recent apps will lead to hide my floating widget and will finish the helper activity, as desired.

But pressing back afterwards, recreates my helper activity. And the helper activity is even shown in the recent apps (although I finished it).

**USAGE and LOG**

I open my activity ONLY AT ONE PLACE like following:

```
L.d(this, "HelperActivity will be created");
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), HelperActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("sidebarId", mSidebar.getId());
getContext().startActivity(i);
```

And my log says:

```
[SidebarView-241]   HelperActivity will be created
[HelperActivity-30] onCreate: 1
```

<< PRESSING RECENT APPS BUTTON ON PHONE >>

```
[HelperActivity-69] NEW TOP
[HelperActivity-45] onSidebarCloseEvent
[HelperActivity-36] onDestroy
```

<< SHOWING RECENT APPS >>

```
[HelperActivity-30] onCreate: 1
```

**Code**

Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activities.HelperActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

Class:

```
    public class HelperActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean mDoCheck = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_helper);

        long sidebarId = -1;
        if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("sidebarId"))
            sidebarId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("sidebarId");

        L.d(this, "onCreate: " + sidebarId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        L.d(this, "onDestroy");

        BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onSidebarCloseEvent(SidebarCloseEvent event)
    {
        L.d(this, "onSidebarCloseEvent");

        mDoCheck = false;
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        if (!mDoCheck)
            return;

        // Pause + ScreenOn => andere Activity is on top!
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean screenOn;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH)
            screenOn = pm.isInteractive();
        else
            screenOn = pm.isScreenOn();

        if (screenOn)
        {
            L.d(this, "NEW TOP");
            BusProvider.getInstance().post(new SidebarCloseEvent(null, true, false));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to return() after calling finish(). Finish() does not immediately kill the activity if there are pending operations to be executed.

Comment: finish is anyway the last function... btw, as the log shows, the activity's finish is executed and finished - `onDestroy` get's called... But whenever I close the recent apps, the activity is recreated...

Answer (score 0):

**CURRENT SOLUTION**

I now worked out following solution:

In my `onCreate` I use following:

```
boolean launchedFromHistory = (flags & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY;
if (launchedFromHistory)
    finish();
```

This seems to work... Still, maybe someone has a comment to that solution or knows something better...

Comment: I can only confirm that a finished activity can be recreated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891905/how-to-remove-activityrecord-of-an-activity-i-explicitly-finish

Comment: How did you defined the flags ?